# Difference between PositiveInteger and PositiveSmallInteger Field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

There is no difference between PositiveInteger and PositiveSmallInteger field in the Django source code. But, Django documentation says,

```
PositiveInteger starts from 0 to 2147483647 and PositiveSmallInteger starts from  0 to 32767.
```

Please clarify me what is the difference between these two types.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those things that is the way it is because it got that way.

Django supports `SmallIntegerField` because Django grew up on PostgreSQL, and PostgreSQL supports smallint. The [PosgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) say

> The smallint type is generally only used if disk space is at a premium.

Also there's a difference in the code if you check the [backends](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends) of Django. There you see it uses the `SMALLINT` feature on some databases, for example [sqlite](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/introspection.py#L27).

```
...
class FlexibleFieldLookupDict:
    # Maps SQL types to Django Field types. Some of the SQL types have multiple
    # entries here because SQLite allows for anything and doesn't normalize the
    # field type; it uses whatever was given.
    base_data_types_reverse = {
        'bool': 'BooleanField',
        'boolean': 'BooleanField',
        'smallint': 'SmallIntegerField',
        'smallint unsigned': 'PositiveSmallIntegerField',
        'smallinteger': 'SmallIntegerField',
        'int': 'IntegerField',
        'integer': 'IntegerField',
        'bigint': 'BigIntegerField',
        'integer unsigned': 'PositiveIntegerField',
        'decimal': 'DecimalField',
        'real': 'FloatField',
...
```